# Why is my props bringing back the action function, not the date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a react app that is pulling down some data, It turns a promise so I am using Thunk. However when I log `this.props`, the getShift action prints out as a function.

The log returns:
{getShifts: ƒ}getShifts: ƒ ()**proto**: Object

Action:

```
 import settings from '../../aws-config.js';
    import Amplify, { Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';
    export const GET_STAFF_SHIFTS = 'get_staff_shifts';
    export const SHIFTS_LOAD_FAIL = 'shifts_load_fail';
    export const getShifts = () => dispatch => {
        console.log('Fetching list of shifts for user...');
        const request = API.get("StaffAPI", "/shifts", {
            headers: {
                   'Accept': 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(response =>

            dispatch({
              type: 'GET_STAFF_SHIFTS',
              payload: response
            })
        )
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch({type: 'SHIFTS_LOAD_FAIL'})
        )
        }
```

reducer:

```
    import { getShifts, GET_STAFF_SHIFTS} from '../actions';
    export default function(state = {}, action) {
      switch(action.type){
        case GET_STAFF_SHIFTS:
            return Object.assign({}, state,{
              start_time: action.payload
            })
            default:
            return state;
      }
    }
```

Action:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Amplify, { Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {getShifts} from '../actions/index';
import settings from '../../aws-config.js';
Amplify.configure(settings);

class StaffRota extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
  this.props.getShifts();
  }
  renderPosts(){
    console.log(this.props);
  return (

    <div></div>
  );


    }
}

function MapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ getShifts }, dispatch);
}
export default connect(null, MapDispatchToProps)(StaffRota);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action creator is supposed to be a function, which is expected. So console logging `this.props.getShifts` will give you a function.

There are two issues here:

first thing you are dispatching the wrong action type 
`dispatch({type: 'GET_STAFF_SHIFTS', ... })` instead of `dispatch({type: GET_STAFF_SHIFTS, ... })` which you are expecting in your reducer.

secondly you ought to use the redux `state` via a `mapStateToProps` function

```
function MapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ getShifts }, dispatch);
}
function MapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    shift: state.start_time OR state.your_reducer.start_time
  }
}

export default connect(MapStateToProps, MapDispatchToProps)(StaffRota);
```

And use this state (that is mapped to prop) via `this.props.shift`.